# Get values between two dates and display in the django template

Tags: python, django

I have two models, `Fluxo` and `Relatorio`. `Fluxo` has a date field, and `Relatorio` has two fields, `data_inicio` and `data_fim`.

I want to make the `Relatorio` display the records in the `Fluxo` between the dates selected in the `Relatorio`.
The way I did does not return any record.

**model**

```
class Relatorio(models.Model):
    data_inicio = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    data_fim  = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)

    def imprimir(self):
       return mark_safe("<a target='_blank' href='%s'>Imprimir</a>" % 
            self.get_absolute_url())
    imprimir.allow_tags = True

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('fluxo_list', args=[self.pk, ])
```

**RelatorioView**

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    inicio = self.kwargs.get('data_inicio')
    fim = self.kwargs.get('data_fim')
    return dict(
        super(RelatorioDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs),
        fluxo_list = Fluxo.objects.filter(data__range=[inicio, fim])
    )
```

Comment: Have you tried `print(self.kwargs.get('data_inicio'))` to see if the value is correct?

Comment: Why aren't you using the model field (`self.object.data_inicio`) ? You are reading the dates from `kwargs`